# How to detect if user is still online with django session

Tags: python, django, authentication, session, middleware

I use Django 2.2 and trying to detect if user is still connected when the user close his browser without logging out
I tried to use some Django packages like qsessions but it need to replace `'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',` with qsession middleware but it makes another error
`django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware not found`
I need your help to get every user session separately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django sessions are not meant to be queried for their content. The user id in the session can be decoded from a session, but you need to iterate through all sessions:

```
from django.contrib.sessions.models import Session
from django.utils import timezone

def get_unexpired_sessions_for_user(user):
    user_sessions = []
    all_sessions = Session.objects.filter(expire_date__gte=timezone.now())
    for session in all_sessions:
        session_data = session.get_decoded()
        if user.pk == session_data.get('_auth_user_id'):
            user_sessions.append(session.pk)
    return Session.objects.filter(pk__in=user_sessions)
```

This approach will work, but will not be performant when you have a lot of sessions in your database.

Comment: Thank you Stefan for you answer but if this function could makes the website more slow, so which way works well without user sessions that used in chat application?